# Gzip compression and decompression between python and java

Tags: java, base64, gzip, compression

I want to decompress a string in java which was gzip compressed and encoded as base64 in python.

What I want to do is to perform a gzip compression on a string in python and I have to decompress that compressed string in java.

First gzip compress the string **'hello'+'\r\n'+'world'** using gzip module in python and then encode that compressed string to base64 in python. The output I get for this is **H4sIAM7yqVcC/8tIzcnJ5+Uqzy/KSQEAQmZWMAwAAAA=**

Then I use the encoded compressed string from python in java to gzip decompress that string. For that I fisrt perform base64 decode on that string in java using `DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary` which will give a byte array and then I perform gzip decompression on that byte array using `GZIPInputStream`. But the decompressed output in java is shown as **helloworld**.

I had a **'\r\n'** in the compressed string in python
but it is not shown in decompressed output. I think the problem here is in base64 encode and decode performed on that string. Please help me to solve this problem.

**String used:**

string = 'hello'+'\r\n'+'world'

**Expected output in java:**

hello
world

**Output got:**

helloworld

**This is the gzip compression code in python:**

```py
String ='hello'+'\r\n'+'world'

out = StringIO.StringIO()

with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=out, mode="w") as f:

        f.write(o)

f=open('compressed_string','wb')

out.getvalue()

f.write(base64.b64encode(out.getvalue()))

f.close()
```

**This is the gzip decompression code in java:**

```java
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("compressed_string")));

try
{
    while((nextLine=reader.readLine())!=null)
    {
        compressedStr +=nextLine;                                    
    }
    finally
    {
      reader.close();
    }
}

byte[] compressed = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(compressedStr);

decomp = decompress(compressed);
```

**This is gzip decompression method in java:**

```java
public static String decompress(final byte[] compressed) throws IOException {
    String outStr = "";
    if ((compressed == null) || (compressed.length == 0)) {
        return "";
    }

    if (isCompressed(compressed)) {
        GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed));
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gis, "UTF-8"));

        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            outStr += line;
        }
    } else {
        outStr = new String(compressed);
    }

    return outStr;
}
```

Comment: The "InputStreamReader" from the "gis"-Stream contaions the correct value. You consume the CRLF while you read the string line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.
>
> Returns:
>
> > A String containing the contents of the line, not including
> >     any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has
> >     been reached

[`bufferedReader.readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) reads by line

so you need to add '\r\n' when you append the string

```
outStr += line + "\r\n";
```

but you should use [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Comment: The gzip compression and decompression between python and java  works fine when the compressed string in python is encoded in base64 and the encoded compressed string is decoded in java during decompression.

But is there a solution without using base64 encoding and decoding?

I have to perform compression in python and write it in a file without any encoding. Then when I read the file in java and convert into byte[] and perform decompression on that byte array I'm not getting the correct decompressed string.